# How to repeat a value each x cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The idea is to have 2 inputs the number and the number of spaces, so lets say those numbers are 2 & 3 it should look like:

```
2
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
2
```

Comment: What code have you tried? What were the results? You can edit your question to add the additional information.

Comment: Zeroes or empty cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If first parameter is in `A1`, second in `B1`, you can enter the following formula in any cell, and fill it down:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(A1),$B$1+1)=1,$A$1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks that's what i need! Can you help me also to invert the pattern, e.g.:00020002 instead of 20002000

Comment: Just switch the last 2 parameters: `=IF(MOD(ROW(A1),$B$1+1)=1,0,$A$1)`, or change the condition: `=IF(MOD(ROW(A1),$B$1+1)<>1,$A$1,0)`. Edit: this would produce 22202220. To get 00020002 the formula should be: `=IF(MOD(ROW(A1),$B$1+1)=0,$A$1,0)`

Comment: No, i'm talking like starting with the ceros, like the example: 00020002, with those formulas the output is 02220222. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is confusing in that there are three 2's and three zeroes. It's unclear on what it should look like if the second number was a *4*. If it is always three of the first number try something using `REPT`. With *2* in A1 and *3* in A2,

```
=A1&rept("0", A2)&A1&rept("0", A2)&A1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=IF(MOD(ROWS($1:1),4)=1,2,0)
```

and then copy down:

[image]